# CompareTo Method: Return Type: GREATER, EQUAL, LESS

Tags: java, class, singly-linked-list, compareto, sortedlist

I'm receiving these 4 errors:
[character expected errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fQCv.png)
[character expected errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J71ad.png)
I'm doing a LinkedList java project that requires the implementation of the CompareTo method. I am rusty on Java and would like some help regarding what I am doing wrong regarding this implementaion. Should I use integers instead of enums?
Should I use switch/case/break instead of if/else?

Here's my Java class file for class ItemType

```
import java.util.Objects;

public class ItemType {
    private int value;

    public ItemType() {
        // Constructor body can be empty if there's no initialization code needed
    }

    public enum compareTo(ItemType item) {
        if (this.getValue() < item.getValue()) {
            return LESS;
        } else if (this.getValue() > item.getValue()) {
            return GREATER;
        } else {
            return EQUAL;
        }
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void initialize(int num) {
        value = num;
    }

    // Assuming Comparison is an enum, you would also need to define it in Java
    //public enum Comparison {
        //LESS,
        //GREATER,
        //EQUAL
    //}
}
```

Here's an example of the SortedLinkedList.java class using the ItemType class method compareTo()

```
while (location.next != null && brake == 0) {
      switch (item_.compareTo(location.item)) {
            case ItemType.GREATER:
                preLoc = location;
                location = location.next;
                break;
            case ItemType.EQUAL:
                System.out.println("\nError: Duplication\n");
                return;
            case ItemType.LESS:
                brake = 1;
                break;
            }
}
```

Comment: Add all error messages as text not as image

Comment: *Should I use integers instead of enums? * yes, that is the common way to use compareTo

Comment: It’s really strange that the answer to your question is already in your code, as a comment: “*Assuming Comparison is an enum, you would also need to define it in Java*”, even followed by a definition of the `Comparison`, converted to a comment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You actually do not need your enum.
Try to implement [Comparable interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).
You can take a look how to do it [here](https://www.happycoders.eu/java/comparator-comparable-compareto/).

Then rework your switch case to work with integer like:

```
    switch (item_.compareTo(location.item)) {
        case 1:
            preLoc = location;
            location = location.next;
            break;
        case 0:
            System.out.println("\nError: Duplication\n");
            return;
        case -1:
            brake = 1;
            break;
    }
```

Happy coding!

**UPD**

Example how to implement (be aware it is not final version and you can provide your own implementation):

```
    public class ItemType implements Comparable<ItemType> {
    private int value;

    public ItemType() {
        // Constructor body can be empty if there's no initialization code needed
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(ItemType o) {
        if (this.value > o.value) {
            return 1;
        }

        if (this.value == o.value) {
            return 0;
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no guaranty that a `compareTo` method only returns `1`, `0`, or `-1`. You have to check whether the returned value is less than or greater than zero.

Comment: Thanks for the better switch rework. Unfortunately, when I looked at the Comparable interface, it mentioned implementing <> pointers which are complex and I haven't learned them yet. Also, I couldn't find the Comparable section for "int" types

Comment: @Holger, you implement it by yourself, so you can implement it in a way to be sure it returns -1, 0, 1

Comment: @mmccoy411, do not worry.
First, there is no pointers in java.
Second, I've updated my answer with compareToImplementation.

Comment: It’s never a good idea to rely on non-standard assumptions. When you come back later, looking at the implementation of `compareTo`, you might have forgotten that you have a caller making that assumptions and wonder why you didn’t simply use `return Integer.compare(value, o.value);` In the end, how much time does fixing the code, e.g. to `switch( Integer.signum(item_.compareTo(location.item))) { … }`, take?

Comment: @Holger In my opinion you are digging to deep. I would like to stay aside of this discussion,just to avoid any possible arguments, excuse me. You can create a topic, thread, whatever in any platform and I will take a part in discussion there but not in comments to this question.

Comment: It’s not a discussion. I explained why your code as is, is not recommended. It would be a discussion if you provided any reasons not to fix it. But of course, you don’t have to.

Answer (score 1):

There is so much wrong here...

```
public enum compareTo(ItemType item)...
```

incorrectly declares an internal enum called compareTo, not a method returning an enum.

If you for whatever reason want to return this enum you need to declare it

```
public enum Comparison {
    LESS, GREATER, EQUAL
}
```

then declare it as a return type of your method and refer the enum type:

```
public Comparison compareTo(ItemType item)...
```

and then in your SortedLinkedList implementation refer to Comparison.LESS, etc, not ItemType.LESS.

Or you could just make ItemType implement Comparable interface, implement the compareTo method and use built in mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

you use the keyword `enum` as return type insteat of the Enum itself, that's why you get the error message:

```
public Comparison compareTo(ItemType item)
```

But I would use the in value, because it is the common way to use `compareTo` in java